# SQL Bit & Report Builder/SSRS Boolean Parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I currently have a SQL Server Database Table that holds a true or false value as a BIT value (i.e. 1 or 0) to represent whether an order was free of charge or not.

I want to use an SSRS Parameter @FOC to influence the SELECT query of the dataset, so that when the selected Parameter is 'True' then I want to include rows with either 0 or 1, but when the Parameter is 'False' I only want records with the value '0'.

I have tried the following but it fails with either a type conversion error (from varchar to bit or varchar to int).

```
SELECT
sl."ref", sl."status", sl."foc"
FROM
sl
WHERE
sl."status" > 10 AND
sl."foc" IN (CASE WHEN @FOC = 'True' THEN '0,1' ELSE '0' END)
ORDER BY sl."dt_created" ASC
```

I know the issue is in the CASE statement within the WHERE block, but what is the trick I'm missing?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `OR` logic:

```sql
SELECT sl.ref,
       sl.status,
       sl.foc
FROM dbo.sl
WHERE sl.status > 10
  AND (@FOC = 1
   OR  sl.foc = @Foc)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

I add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as the query plans may well be different for the 2 different parameters; this forces the query plan to be regenerated.

You can read more about `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` in [Revisiting catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) and [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).